# Tensorflow streaming_dynamic_auc returns 0 value and None op

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand how to aggregate metric variables in Tensorflow and I came across `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_dynamic_auc`. It aggregates predictions and labels, which seems straightforward, but what puzzles me is that the first run after initialization gives 0, and all subsequent runs work fine. Here is the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random


random.seed(121231)
n_points = 1000
y_true = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(n_points)]
y_pred = [random.random() for _ in xrange(n_points)]
pds = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_points])
lbs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [n_points])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    auc_dynamic = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_dynamic_auc(predictions=pds, labels=lbs)
    auc = tf.metrics.auc(predictions=pds, labels=lbs)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    auc_dynamic_val, auc_dynamic_op = sess.run(auc_dynamic, {pds:y_pred, lbs:y_true})
    auc_val, auc_op = sess.run(auc, {pds: y_pred, lbs: y_true})
    print("1st run. Dynamic auc val %.7f, op: %s" % (auc_dynamic_val, auc_dynamic_op))
    print("1st run. Auc val %.7f, op: %s" % (auc_val, auc_op))
    auc_dynamic_val, auc_dynamic_op = sess.run(auc_dynamic, {pds: y_pred, lbs: y_true})
    auc_val, auc_op = sess.run(auc, {pds: y_pred, lbs: y_true})
    print("2nd run. Dynamic auc val %.7f, op: %s" % (auc_dynamic_val, auc_dynamic_op))
    print("2nd run. Auc val %.7f, op: %s" % (auc_val, auc_op))
```

It prints:

```
1st run. Dynamic auc val 0.0000000, op: None
1st run. Auc val 0.0000000, op: 0.5043121
2nd run. Dynamic auc val 0.5043422, op: None
2nd run. Auc val 0.5043121, op: 0.5043121
```

There is a discrepancy between `dynamic auc` and `auc` Dynamic auc `op` is always `None` and its value is 0 at the first run. At the second run values match though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's intended behavior. TF metrics output a tuple of value and update op, that update value. So in first run the actual value, the first output of a metric will be 0. If you just print the both values two times, you'll see that on the second run both values will be non zero.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
        auc_tf = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_dynamic_auc(predictions=pds, labels=lbs)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        auc_tf_val = sess.run(auc_tf, {pds:y_pred, lbs:y_true})
        print(auc_tf_val)
        auc_tf_val = sess.run(auc_tf, {pds: y_pred, lbs: y_true})
        print(auc_tf_val)
```

P.S. I don't know your particular application and TF version you're using, but I guess it's better to use `tf.metrics.auc`. Contrib module will be deprecated in future versions.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc

Edit: In regard to particular case, mentioned in the question. update_op's value is always `None` because it's computed differently, In case contrib module metrics it is  `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'>`, while  metrics module return plain tensor, that can be evaluated inside session, therefore has value.

Comment: I am studying different implementation of aucs, not really interested in using it. Another question is that its op is always `None`. And I can't add it summaries. If I do `tf.summary.scalar('metrics_auc', auc_value)` I get only zeros, and can't add as `tf.summary.scalar('metrics_auc', auc_op)` because `auc_op` is `None`.

Comment: It depends on where you're looking. Tensorboard? To add summaries there you need to merge them and write with `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Comment: If you run my code and replace `_` with `auc_op` and look at it, it is always `None`. And adding it to summary results in an error. Also I use a quite big system based on `CustomEstoimator`. I have logging hooks and summary saver hooks, both output zeros for this particular auc. The default auc works just fine.

Comment: This is easily could be caused by data. Try using it in isolation with some predefined constants as logits/labels

Comment: Hm, not sure I follow. If I use above code to print `auc_op` for `tf.metrics.auc` it has values at every call. `auc_op` for `streaming_dynamic_auc` always is `None`. How is this cause by data? I use the same data for both.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Updated answer. Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Hm, I guess your answers makes it clearer. Thank you! I will wait several days and will mark my question as answered.