# How to use tensorflow.metrics.x with SummarySaverHook and Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is related to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15115). I use custom `tf.estimator.Estimator` and want to see learning curves for several different metrics. I use `tf.train.SummarySaverHook` and `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook`. For example, I want to add `accuracy` and look at it on Tensorboad. I do the following:

```
acc_value, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=preds)
tf.summary.scalar('metrics_accuracy', acc_op)
```

And everything works, BUT it works because I used `acc_op` which is always non zero. On the other hand, some metrics return `None` for its `op` and the only way to use them is to do `tf.summary.scalar('metrics_accuracy', acc_value)`. And here is the problem which was discussed in [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15115). First value for `metrics.x` value is always zero, and that's the value that is always printed during training. How to use it?

P.S.: The metric that doesn't have a value for its op is `dynamic_streaming_auc` and the problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567764/tensorflow-streaming-dynamic-auc-returns-0-value-and-none-op). And no I am not using it, I am using a modified version of it - custom auc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. It is tricky. One can do it by modifying `SummarySaverHook` to call `update_ops` in `before_run` method. Here are the steps.

1) In `model_fn` defining estimator add metric op to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` and its value to `tf.summary.scalar`:

```py
acc_value, acc_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=preds)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, acc_op)
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', acc_value)
```

2) Create `UpdateOpsHook` that will call all `update_ops`:

```
class UpdateOpsHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    """Hook to execute all `update_ops` from tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS before each run.
    One needs to call `update_ops` to see metric values during training."""

    def __init__(self):
        # Get all update_ops for (streaming) metrics, which are added
        # into `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` during creation of the graph
        self._update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope='metrics')

    def begin(self):
        self._global_step_tensor = tf.train.get_global_step()
        if self._global_step_tensor is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Global step should be created to use UpdateOpsHook.")

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        # Run `update_ops`
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(fetches=self._update_ops)
```

3. Add this hook into training `EstimatorSpec` and don't forget to add the scalar into eval `EstimatorSpec`:

```
update_op_hook = UpdateOpsHook()
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    summary_train_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
            save_steps=100,
            output_dir='train_summaries',
            summary_op=summary_op)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=preds, loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train_op,
                                          training_hooks=[summary_train_hook, update_op_hook]
                                          )
eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': (acc_value, acc_op)}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, predictions=preds, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```